# Getting child node count from mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, hierarchical-data

I'm working with a recursive table and I'm trying to build a query to get my child node counts however my query fails to return the correct count when I restrict it by the `basic_user_id`. 
The idea behind the design is to enable different users to have their own hierarchy of companies, however I can't have them conflicting with each other which is what appears to be happening.

[image]

**My query**

```
select * , count(c2.company_id ) 

from company_user c1 left join company_user c2 on c2.parent_id = c1.company_id  

where c1.company_id in (1337) 
and c1.basic_user_id = 23

group by c1.company_id;
```

`basic_user_id = 23` should return a count of 1 which it does correctly

[image]

Now when I change `basic_user_id` to 541, I'm expecting it to return a count of 0 however it still seems to return a count of 1.

[image]

How do I get `basic_user_id = 541` to return a count of 0 and `basic_user_id = 23` to return a count of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? You can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f61/2

I have added `AND child_tab.basic_user_id = parent_tab.basic_user_id` ON clause. Because You are doing `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT parent_tab.company_id, COUNT(child_tab.company_id) 
FROM company_user parent_tab LEFT JOIN company_user child_tab
    ON child_tab.parent_id = parent_tab.company_id  
      AND child_tab.basic_user_id = parent_tab.basic_user_id
WHERE parent_tab.company_id IN (1337) 
    AND parent_tab.basic_user_id = 23
GROUP BY parent_tab.company_id;
```

Comment: This query is correct, as you'll see in my own answer I was just missing the second join. Shame on me for overlooking that :-/ Anyhow, I'm going to mark your answer as the best answer since I like how much clearer your query is.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, I just needed to add a second join.

```
select * , count(c2.company_id ) 

from deepblue.company_user c1 left join deepblue.company_user c2 on c2.parent_id = c1.company_id 
and c1.basic_user_id = c2.basic_user_id 

where c1.company_id in (1337) 
and c1.basic_user_id= 541

group by c1.company_id;
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that you've already solved your question. and don't be shame! good question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
count(c2.company_id )
```

to

```
sum(case when c2.company_id is null then 0 else 1 end)
```

(please check syntax of case statement for your DB)

Comment: I think I would need to add a second where clause on c2.basic_user_id in order for the join to be restricted and a null result returned. I think I'm better off with the second join as shown in my own answer.